# Combining multiple files by a common column and adding values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have around 600 .txt files in this format

```
Position    SRR7622449
chr1_944296 1
chr1_944307 1
chr1_946247 1
chr1_1014274    1
chr1_1401954    1
chr1_1541864    1
```

Each file has 2 columns, a column called Position which exists in every file; a second column which denotes the identifier and is different in every file.

The number of rows in every file is different.

I wish to merge all of these 600+ files into one dataframe and add whichever values are duplicated so that in the end I have unique rows.

This is what I tried first

```
require(readr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

files <- dir(pattern = "*.txt")
data <- files %>% map(read_tsv) %>% bind_rows()
```

This gave me a huge dataframe and i found out that the Position column is now duplicated.
I want this result:

```
Position    SRR7622449  SRR7622450
chr1_944296 2   1
```

instead of

```
Position    SRR7622449  SRR7622450
chr1_944296 1   NA
chr1_944296 1   1
```

When I try

```
data %>% group_by(Position) %>% summarise_each(funs(max))
```

I seem to be losing values. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Try `data %>% group_by(Position) %>% summarise(across(.fns = sum, na.rm = TRUE))` Or for `dplyr` < 1.0.0  `data %>% group_by(Position) %>% summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! That worked! How do I tag this as the correct answer so I can close this question?

Comment: Actually, this has been asked before so I marked this question as duplicate of original question.